# Fetching city name from json with swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I need help with proper parsing of OpenWeatherAPI. I need to fetch city name.

I always got this line of code:

```
 021-09-23 08:16:13.526604+0200 Clima[1943:50811] Writing analzed variants.
Optional("")
```

This is my JSON:

[JSON example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHMlu.png)

This is my struct for api:

```
struct WeatherData: Decodable{
    let message: String?
    let list: [List]?
    
}

struct List: Decodable{
    let name: String?
}
```

And my function for fetching json:

```
func parseJSON(weatherData: Data)   {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
            print(decodedData.list![0].name!)
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I need to fetch a name. I understand that I need to make in my main struct WeatherData let for another struct and then use it. E.g. decodedData.list.name to fetch some data.

One more question: should I always use ? (optional) when fetching data from JSON ?

Comment: You should only need to use optional if the data may not always appear in the response

Comment: I removed optionals and I only got this: 2021-09-23 08:36:32.060522+0200 Clima[2132:60570] Writing analzed variants. I'm using simulator.

Comment: You are using the ***find*** API of `OpenWeatherMap`. The value for key `list` – by the way OWM sends consistent and well documented data, declare only those properties as optional which could be missing according to the docs – is an array because there are many cities with the same name in different countries and even in the same country. To parse the array you need a loop or a `filter` expression.

Comment: How should I know exact output e.g. if decodedData.list[0].name == "Paris". I'm waiting user to input it. I'm not sure how to loop it properly because I'm using only user output (name of a city).

Comment: As you are searching for Paris the found names are most likely Paris, too 

Comment: This was an example, how should I filter names when I don't know what user will input.

Comment: Show the user more information for example the state and/or the country and let him select the city. As I said `list` – as the name implies – contains a ***list*** of all found cities along with all the data

Comment: I don't understand why in my json there is like List then 0,1,2,3 then sections like weather, main, sys etc. Why there is no just list with weather, main etc. Why cannot I access them with just decodedData.main.name ? I understand that there are also maybe other cities with the same name. When you use weather app do you want to type city and a name of your county? I will later add function to ask for permission to use user current location.

Comment: What is so difficult to understand? For example there are 34 cities with name Springfield in the US. How should `OpenWeatherMap` know which Springfield you mean. So it gives you a list of all cities along with all specific geo-data and weather-data. As I said show the user a dialog with unique information of all cities and let him select the city he wants.

Comment: I understand what you want to say. Problem was with fetchCity function. I made it but I didn't call it from anywhere. Thanks for help